# Input values to textfields, stream back to website

Tags: java, jsoup

I connected to a website, used JSoup to find the "textfield" ID's, input the values, now i need to stream it out.

Can someone please help me with the correct coding to stream the "modified" doc back to the website?

```
if (source == enter2) 
{

            String URL = "http://www.clubvip.co.za/Login.aspx";
            Element number;
            Element pass;
            Element keyword;
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
                number = doc.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CellNumberRadText").attr("value", "number");
                System.out.println(number);
                pass = doc.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PasswordRadText").attr("value", "password");
                System.out.println(pass);
                keyword = doc.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_KeyWordRadText").attr("value", "keyword");
                System.out.println(keyword);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing it like this?

If you need to login to that webpage, simply take arguments and send them via `HTTP POST` request to page where `<form>` points to

which is `<form method="post" action="login.aspx">`

Answer (score 0):

**Instead** of what you are doing:

```
Jsoup.connect("http://www.clubvip.co.za/Login.aspx")//
     .data("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CellNumberRadText", "number", 
           "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PasswordRadText", "password",
           "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_KeyWordRadText", "password").post();
```

not tested, so possibly not 100% correct...

Comment: Nope, not working, the problem is that the difference is the .data and .attr, with this example, it sees the iD of the textfield, but i dont think it knows where to put that "number" or "password" in, since in .attr you spesify that it has to go into the value="".

Comment: What kind of exception/return value do you get?